# Why is my AWS App Runner application not deploying?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-app-runner

I'm trying to deploy an application with AWS App Runner and initially had a successful deploy. However, as I make changes to the app, then push to GitHub, the application deployment begins, runs for about 20 minutes then fails.

Here are the last few lines from the deploy log:

```
[Build] Successfully built 96fba6016991
[Build] Successfully tagged application-image:latest
[AppRunner] Failed to deploy your application source code.
```

Then the application rolls back. I cannot locate any other logs with any additional information.

Where can I find more descriptive logs? Why is my application not deploying?

Comment: Thanks for reporting, I'm getting the same exact error.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Deploying the application locally works fine for me.

Comment: This is typically an application error. If the container has errors and is not able to terminate properly, another deployment will fail. I suggest you look through logs, cloudtrail, cloudwatch to see what is going on. Sometimes not putting a timeout on network connections can cause applications to hang.

Comment: `Where can I find more descriptive logs?` Check the cloudwatch, cloudformations, cloudtrail. Indeed in some services it is not so obvious